# STM32 ADC Continuous Conv Mode does not automatically start conversion

Tags: gcc, arm, microcontroller, stm32, adc

I am trying to configure ADC over a STM32F411RE in simple Continuous Conv Mode. I used CubeMX to generate the code based on HAL drivers and this is some parts of the generated code which intialize ADC:

```
/* ADC1 init function */
void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{

    /**Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion) 
    */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV8;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_8B;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}
```

and here is the main function:

```
int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  uint8_t analogVal;
  uint8_t string[] = "Poll failed\n";

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  HAL_Delay(1000);
  if( HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1) == HAL_OK) HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2,(uint8_t*)"STRT OK\n",8,100);
  else HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2,(uint8_t *)HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1),1,100);
  while (1)
  {
  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    if(HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1,1) == HAL_OK){
      analogVal = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2,&analogVal,sizeof(analogVal),100);
    }
    else{
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2,string,sizeof(string)-1,100);
    }
    HAL_Delay(100);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}
```

If I compile and upload this code into the microcontroller, no more than once analogVal would be transmitted over UART. But if I place HAL_ADC_Start function inside the while loop, HAL_ADC_PollForConversion returned value will be HAL_OK in every cycle of while and there will be a analogVal to report.

My question is, why should I everytime ask the ADC to start if I have enabled  ContinuousConvMode?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am sure that the EOC flag setting is the problem. `hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;`  should be changed to `hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = EOC_SEQ_CONV;`.

Your current option `ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV` acts like an enable of single conversion, but you need `EOC_SEQ_CONV` aka sequential conversions.

It is pretty much the same problem that has been discussed [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/202952/56348).

Answer (score 0):

According to reference manual (RM0383, p. 214):

> The Scan mode is selected by setting the SCAN bit in the ADC_CR1
>   register. Once this bit has been set, the ADC scans all the channels
>   selected in the ADC_SQRx registers (for regular channels) or in the
>   ADC_JSQR register (for injected channels). A single conversion is
>   performed for each channel of the group. After each end of conversion,
>   the next channel in the group is converted automatically. **If the CONT
>   bit is set, regular channel conversion does not stop at the last
>   selected channel in the group but continues again from the first
>   selected channel**.

So additionaly you have to declare group of channels and amount of them in ADC_SQR register (in your case it will be only one channel).

EDIT: 
Please note that in your example which you posted 
there is external triggering of each conversion by Timer:

```
 g_AdcHandle.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONV_T1_CC1;
```

But right I haven't seen initialization of timer in the rest of  this code.

Comment: thanks for replying to my question. But according to this post (https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/arm/stm32/adc/)  ScanMode is not required as we are not going to use more than one ADC Channel